# A poly-moly-holy quine. (Well, it's not, but the title's cool.)

Tags: quine, polyglot, answer-chaining

This is an answer chaining puzzle, where each answer must add on to the last.

The \$n\$th submission must output its own source code in the \$n\$th language and the \$n−1\$ languages before it.

A language can be either a dialect or a major version of a language, so Python version 2.121 is only counted as version 2 and Common Lisp and Clojure are considered different languages. This excludes compiler flags.

You can post 2 answers in a row, but have to use different languages.

The winner of this puzzle is the person to submit the second-to-last quine if there have been no new quines for a week. The aim of this puzzle is to go on as long as it can, so if you want the green tick, you'll have to respect that.

Have fun.

Comment: But other than that, creative and cool challenge! (Just a note, don't be offended by the downvotes, they are just indicating whether it would be good for the site in it's current form). Also, "output its own source code in n different languages" may seem a little bit too hard for an answer-chaining questions, so you may want to change that to the current language instead of all the previous languages.

Comment: Well actually re: scoring, one thing you can do is copy the other polyglot-chaining problem, which has a scoring metric based on both number of languages and code size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91074/discussion-between-andrew-and-ascii-only).

Comment: Are there any rules on one person posting two answers in a row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 187 bytes

```
var s=1
<0?"":"var s=1{0}<0?{1}{1}:{1}{3}{1};Write(s,(char)10,(char)34,(char)39,s)//.1+d*fao;!?l{1}var s=1{1}ar*3dr{2}";Write(s,(char)10,(char)34,(char)39,s)//.1+d*fao;!?l"var s=1"ar*3dr'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/vyyxSKHY1pDLxsBeSclKCcqtNqgFClQb1gKRFYgyBrGsw4syS1I1inU0kjMSizQNDaAMYxMYw1KnWFNfX89QO0UrLTHfWtE@B6gNZqZhbWKRlnFKUbVRrRI5RsEcpwQxRv3/fwA)

[Try C# Online](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIodjWkMvGwF5JyUoJyq02qAUKVBvWApEViDIGsazDizJLUjWKdTSSMxKLNA0NoAxjExjDUqdYU19fz1A7RSstMd9a0T4HqA1mpmFtYpGWcUpRtVGtEjlGwRynBDFG/f9/AA)

Let's add a 2D language, why not?

Comment: Just for your info: if you plan to submit again, the quine must only work properly for this lang and another one of your choice, while still including the C# code.

Comment: No. You have to use other people's languages, leave all the previous stuff intact, while adding on your thing. However, the result only needs to work like a quine for whatever lang you choose next and the one in the last submission. If I added something as the third last submission, the quine could work like mud in my language but work perfectly in yours and in the last one.

Comment: I'm reverting it to the polyquine challenge.

Comment: I get `1 What do you want 0/0 to be? What do you want 0/0 to be? ` when I try running this in Befunge, lol

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Yeah, if you're going to add Befunge-98 to this, then you're either going to have to get rid of the `"`s in the `C#` code, or have to use `nk'`, e.g. like [this quine](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/P7lIvUg9OSVbRz1bx0E9@/9/AA)

Comment: @JoKing Was just seeing if I could implement a quine in Befunge with still maintaining compatibility with the previous languages easily; I probably could not solve a hard solution to this problem

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 63 bytes

```cs
var s="var s={0}{1}{0};Write(s,(char)34,s)";Write(s,(char)34,s)
```

Just to start it off.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIodhWCUJVG9RWG9YCSevwosySVI1iHY3kjMQiTWMTnWJNJWyC//8DAA)

Comment: I've written a polyglot with ><> ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/vyyxSKHY1pDLxsBeSclKCcqtNqgFClQb1gKRFYgyBrGsw4syS1I1inU0kjMSizQNDaAMYxMYw1KnWFNf3y7fBqgaZpRhbWKRlnFKUbVRrRIJJsCcogTRrf7/PwA "><> – Try It Online")), but I can't post it since it breaks the 50+ chars rule `:(`

Comment: @JoKing It also seems to break the no STDERR rule ("something smells fishy...")

Comment: @JoKing it isn't impossible, [see here](https://tio.run/##Sy7Wzc3Py9ctzkjNyfn/vyyxSKHYVglCVRvUVhvWAklr5/y84vycVL3wosySVI1iHY3kjMQiTWMTnWJNJXyS//8DAA). Granted, the two languages are basically the same, but you know, it's the implementation that counts

Comment: @JoKing and we can make it work for all 5 c# compilers if we wrap the whole thing into a lambda, since all 5 basically are the same language

Comment: Okay, but try making a polyquine with a language that isn't C# and see how far you get. (P.S. I've always been annoyed with the implementation vs languages ruling when it comes to polyglots. You wouldn't post a program and say "This is a polyglot with all 16 implementations of the language, because all of them work exactly the same". It's only really a polyglot if none of the languages do the exact same thing with the program)

Comment: An example of a bullshit polyglot is your previous answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180896/76162) which "scored" infinity, because the "languages" had literally no difference between them